# C++ Way of handling multiple inheritance for interfaces

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am looking at refactoring a lot of code and have discussed a bit in relations to the best way of handling inheritance. Given the following three classes

```
class Listener_Interface {
  public:
    virtual void message(data& data);
}
class Timing_Interface {
  public:
  virtual void timerEvent(data& data);
}
class Action_Interface {
  public:
  virtual void action(data& data);
}
```

There is a need for a class to implement all these plus provide a some extra specifik methods.
Should I inherit like this:

```
class NewClass_Interface :
 public Listener_Interface,
 public Timing_Interface,
 public Action_Interface {
  public:
    virtual void newMethod();
}
class NewClass : NewClass_Interface {
    ....
}
```

or

```
class NewClass_Interface {
  public:
    virtual void newMethod();
}
class NewClass :
 public NewClass_Interface
 public Listener_Interface,
 public Timing_Interface,
 public Action_Interface {
    ....
}
```

To me the previous seems more correct and easier to test etc. But for some reason all the classes and code looks lite the latter.

Comment: Your methods should be virtual pure for `_Interface` classes to be interfaces.

Comment: They really are, just did a description of the inheritance structure. Didn't really pay any attention to the actual method declarations.

Comment: The biggest benefit of an interface is to achieve some logical separation of concerns. If the new method doesn't make sense without the context of the other interfaces, don't create a new interface just for it - it wouldn't make sense. On the other hand, if it's a totally separable concept, then by all means make an interface.

Comment: I agree, this is a refactoring of existing code.

It seems to be ending up in single inheritance and a splitting NewClass (which is really an old existing class) into several more "objectified" classes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your logic. Sometimes you might want your `NewClass_Interface` to not necessarily have a relation with Listener, Timing and Action. But since it doesn't look like the case here, I agree with you. The better you constraint the use of your interfaces, the more reliable your code will be.

So I would go with this:

```
class Listener_Interface {
  public:
    virtual void message(data& data) = 0;
}
class Timing_Interface {
  public:
  virtual void timerEvent(data& data) = 0;
}
class Action_Interface {
  public:
  virtual void action(data& data) = 0;
}
```

(Observe how I make your methods **pure virtual** in order to make your classes **real** interfaces)

```
class NewClass_Interface :
 public Listener_Interface,
 public Timing_Interface,
 public Action_Interface
{
  public:
    virtual void newMethod() = 0;
}

class NewClass : NewClass_Interface {
    ....
}
```

This way you'll have better control on what is going on.

Also, I would advise you of using the most common standard for Interfaces naming: `IListener`, `ITiming`, `IAction` and `INewClass`.

Comment: Thanks, the zero is really there in the code, I just forgot about it when writing the question. Don't have internet access on the computer with the code on it, at the moment.

Comment: Also on that note;
I am moving the Listener parts to a separate class so that inheritance will   be removed for this specifik implementation.

The Timing relations will be removed completely so it will probably end up in a just 2 Interfaces to inherit.

Mostly wanted a sanity check, which you provided excellently.

Comment: It is all up to you. The only secret here is thinking ahead to avoid confusion and bad code reliability in the future.

Comment: It is really not named _Interface, it follows the corporate standard at work which is something different, not really good either though.